# No Result trying to get echo from other file with cUrl

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I cannot figure out why i am getting nothing back from my setup.I am using cUrl to get the returned results (events) from an other php file.

In my first file i have a case with a function like this:

```
...
case 'list':    
    $events = $_crs->listCourse($_REQUEST["from"], $_REQUEST["to"], $_REQUEST["category"], $_REQUEST["limit"]);
    return $events;
break;
...
```

In the executing file i have another funtion like this:

```
function url_get_contents ($Url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

And this function is called by this line of code:

```
$list = url_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "CalendarEvents.php?set=list&from=$from&to=$to&category=&limit=15");
```

Answer (score 0):

Like most PHP functions, the cURL functions return values that are meaningful.  You might want to test the value of *$output* and if it is FALSE, visualize the cURL error information.

```
<?php // /demo/curl_get_example.php
/**
 * Demonstrate the basics of cURL GET-method request
 * Something like demo/curl_get_example.php?url=http://twitter.com
 *
 * http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Class GET_Response_Object
{
    public $href, $title, $http_code, $errno, $info, $document;

    public function __construct($href, $get_array=[], $title=NULL)
    {
        // ACTIVATE THIS TO AVOID TIMEOUT FOR LONG RUNNING SCRIPT
        // set_time_limit(10);

        // STORE THE CALL INFORMATION
        $this->href  = $href;
        $this->title = $title;

        // PREPARE THE GET STRING
        $get_string = http_build_query($get_array);
        if ($get_string) $get_string = '?' . $get_string;

        // MAKE THE REQUEST
        if (!$this->my_curl($href, $get_string))
        {
            // ACTIVATE THIS TO SEE THE ERRORS AS THEY OCCUR
            // trigger_error("Errno: $this->errno; HTTP: $this->http_code; URL: $this->href", E_USER_WARNING);
        }
    }

    protected function my_curl($url, $get_string, $timeout=3)
    {
        // PREPARE THE CURL CALL
        $curl = curl_init();

        // HEADERS AND OPTIONS APPEAR TO BE A FIREFOX BROWSER REFERRED BY GOOGLE
        $header[] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
        $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
        $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
        $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
        $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
        $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
        $header[] = "Pragma: "; // BROWSERS USUALLY LEAVE THIS BLANK

        // SET THE CURL OPTIONS - SEE http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL,            $url . $get_string  );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0'  );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header  );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_REFERER,        'http://www.google.com'  );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING,       'gzip,deflate'  );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,    TRUE  );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE  );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE  );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        $timeout  );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,        TRUE   );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,    TRUE   );

        // SET THE LOCATION OF THE COOKIE JAR (WILL BE OVERWRITTEN)
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,     'cookie.txt' );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,      'cookie.txt' );

        // IF USING SSL, THIS INFORMATION MAY BE IMPORTANT
        // http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#110457
        // http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#115993
        // http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#113754
        // REDACTED IN 2015 curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE  );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE  );

        // RUN THE CURL REQUEST AND GET THE RESULTS
        $this->document  = curl_exec($curl);
        $this->errno     = curl_errno($curl);
        $this->info      = curl_getinfo($curl);
        $this->http_code = $this->info['http_code'];
        curl_close($curl);

        // RETURN DOCUMENT SUCCESS SIGNAL
        return $this->document;
    }
}


// USAGE EXAMPLE: YOU COULD HAVE SOMETHING LIKE THIS
$url = isset($_GET["url"]) ? $_GET["url"] : 'http://twitter.com';

// BUT BECAUSE IT IS ON MY SERVER, I HAVE HARD-CODED THIS
$url = 'https://twitter.com/RayPaseur';

// TRY THE REMOTE WEB SERVICE
$response = new Get_Response_Object($url);

// SHOW THE WORK PRODUCT
echo "<pre>";
if (!$response->document) var_dump($response);
echo htmlentities($response->document);

// SHOW THE COOKIES, IF ANY
echo PHP_EOL;
echo file_get_contents('cookie.txt');
```

Comment: sorry i dont even know where to start? Could you please keep your anser simple as possible? And give me example based on the code from my question?